# Q: How to handle all inbound and outbound mails in Office365/Exchange online?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

What are alternatives to Exchange Transport Agents if you’d need to implement the logic to handle *all* mails coming into or out of the organization in Office365/Exchange online? Is MS Graph or Outlook notification REST API are reliable and fast enough to get hold of mail messages before end users receive them? Or, would EWS API be a better option? Or are there any undocumented APIs in Office365/Exchange that would allow to see all organization mails without setting up individual mailbox subscriptions? I would appreciate any help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent of Exchange Transport Agents in Office 365.  You can use webhooks but you will receive the webhook when the email is delivered to the user's mailbox, so your app sees it at the same time as a user does, if he/she were logged into Outlook or another app at that time.  So, that won't meet your scenario.

What type of processing are you looking to do using a Transport agent?

Comment: In our product that we currently offer for on-prem Exchange deployments,  the transport agent inspects all in/out-bound mail messages and carries out admin defined actions based on inspection results such as updating message subject/headers, adding text or converting message bodies, removing or updating attachments, etc. I suppose that webhooks could be used, but I will then need to find a way how to lock or hide a message before the end user opens it. Any suggestions how this could be done?

Comment: BTW, according to my research, it seems that there is some direct “service-to-service” APIs, which would apparently allow to implement capabilities of transport agents in Office365. I was told that there is 3rd party antivirus product that can scan all emails and documents in Office365 in the same way as it would be done on-prem. Does Microsoft have a special API for security companies like they had Virus Scanning API for Exchange and SharePoint in the past?