# Outlook Add-in NodeJS : get mail received notification

Tags: node.js, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to write an Outlook add-in in NodeJS which reads the content of a mail and search for some specific strings. To do so, I need to get a notification when a new mail is received.

However, the event-based actions described in the Microsoft documentation only seem to refer to writing/sending mails, and not receiving them : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Has anyone ever dealt with this situation, or would be able to lead me to the proper notification ? I am searching the "OnMessageReceived" kind of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item only. You can handle item-level events only (or selection change with a pinnable task pane).

Consider using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) for handling incoming emails, see [Q: How to handle all inbound and outbound mails in Office365/Exchange online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568428/q-how-to-handle-all-inbound-and-outbound-mails-in-office365-exchange-online) for more information.

Comment: Ok it all makes sense now ! I indeed found documentation to interact with the "current element", but couldn't find something event-based. I will use this approach then. I cannot use Graph as I wish my add-on to not ask for any token/credentials/other secrets.